# How to verify new fields in json without fail

Tags: match, karate

I have the following scenario:

```
Given path /resource
And request data
When method POST
Then status 200
And match response contains resourceResponse
```

If resource adds a new field, how can I get that info without fail? I mean I can do `* match response == resourceResponse` but in such case test case fails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match contains`.

```
* def response1 = { foo: 'bar', hello: 'world' }
* def response2 = { foo: 'bar', hello: 'world', extra: 'blah' }
* match response2 contains response1
```